# Expanding div on mouse hover on a image which is in the center of that div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to place 4 divs horizontally, with a small image on the center of each divs; on mouse hover on that image, that div should enlarge showing more contents.
Here is that 'plus' image link-

http://www.nike.com/etc/designs/nike/pes/images/plus.png

```
<div id="hov_text"
    style="position: relative; width: 1350px; height: 400px; margin- top: 20px;">
    <div id="ord1">
        <h3 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px; color: black;">SHOES</h3>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">MEN'S SHOES</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Running</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Basketball</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">NikeiD</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Soccer</h5>
        <img class="ord1_img"
            style="height: 20px; margin-left: 100px; width: 30px;"
            src="img/plus.png" />
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div id="ord2"
        style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; float: left; width: 20%; height: 200px; background-color: #ffffff; border-right: 2px solid #d9d8cd;">
        <h3 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px; color: black;">Clothing</h3>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">MEN'S
            CLOTHING</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">T-Shirts</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Jackets &
            Vests</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Hoddies &
            Swetshirts</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Pants</h5>
        <img class="ord1_img"
            style="height: 20px; margin-left: 100px; width: 30px;"
            src="img/plus.png" />
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div id="ord3"
        style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; float: left; width: 20%; height: 200px; background-color: #ffffff; border-right: 2px solid #d9d8cd;">
        <h3 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px; color: black;">GEAR</h3>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">MEN'S GEAR</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Accessories</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">SPARQ</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Socks</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Bags &
            Backpacks</h5>
        <img class="ord1_img"
            style="height: 20px; margin-left: 100px; width: 30px;"
            src="img/plus.png" />
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div id="ord4"
        style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; float: left; width: 20%; height: 200px; background-color: #ffffff;">
        <h3 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px; color: black;">Others</h3>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Clearence</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">ASDF</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">NFL</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Sportswear</h5>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 20px;">Soccer</h5>
        <img class="ord1_img"
            style="height: 20px; margin-left: 100px; width: 30px;"
            src="img/plus.png" />
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use on animate function in jquery  ,

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_ani_borderspacing) link , that may help you